# How to move lines containing specific strings to top of file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, text-formatting

How can I move lines containing specific strings (ie. 005, and 007) to the top of the target file?

Contents of target file:

```
XXX_008
XXX_001
XXX_002
XXX_009
XXX_003
XXX_006
XXX_005 ----> located here
XXX_007 ----> and here
XXX_004
```

How can I move lines `XXX_005` and `XXX_007` to the top? Retaining the rest of the files order? Like so:

```
XXX_005 ----> now here
XXX_007 ----> and here
XXX_008
XXX_001
XXX_002
XXX_009
XXX_003
XXX_006
XXX_004
```

all the rest retain the same order they were originally in.

... it would be nice to be able to only specify only the numbers when moving lines since I always use double zero padded numbers like any-name_001, any-name_002, etc.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
<file gawk '/_005/,/_007/ {
  top[i++]=$0
  next
}
{
  botom[j++]=$0
}
END {
  for(k in top)
    print top[k]
  for(k in botom)
    print botom[k]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

first `cat` the lines with matched pattern, then those with revert matched pattern:

```
cat <(grep -x 'XXX_00[57]' infile) <(grep -xv 'XXX_00[57]' infile)
```

***note:*** as you mentioned move lines with specific above pattern, then you may need to remove `-x` option from the command which that is used to match that pattern as in whole line.

Comment: Or just `{ grep -x 'XXX_00[57]' infile; grep -xv 'XXX_00[57]' infile; } > outfile`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519179/how-to-move-lines-containing-specific-strings-to-top-of-file/519217?noredirect=1#comment959485_519217) is better and more compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed` alongwith it's extended regex engine enabled, we can do the problem. The hold space contains all the lines that need to be moved north, while the pattern space contains the nonmatching lines.

```
$ sed -Ee '
    /_005|_007/{
      /\n/!{
        H;$!d;g;s/.//;b
      }
      G
      s/(.*\n.*)(\n.*)(\n\n.*)/\1\3\2/
      h;s/.*\n(\n)/\1/
      x;s/\n\n.*//
      $bend
      s/^/\n/;D
    }
    $bend
    N;s/^/\n/;D
    :end
    x;G;s/.//
' input.txt
```

With perl we maintain two arrays to store the matching nd nonmatching lines:

```
$ perl -ne 'push @{/_005|_007/ ? \@A : \@B}, $_}{print @A, @B' input.txt
```